# Files visibility while adding them to a library

Tags: apex, files, contentversion, contentdocument, libraries

I am currently trying to figure out one problem connected to Libraries and ContendDocuments.
So I currently have 2 libraries. One library is to store all of the files in the system, while another one is only for files with one field set up to Active.

As a user I want to add a file in the library with active files by choosing files from another library, but I want to see only those files, that field is set up to active. Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way of doing this currently, There is an [idea open for the same.](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TtXCQA0)